# Android Custom Layout Manager with scroll both vertical and horizontal and fill items by vertical first

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager, recyclerview-layout

I'm developing an Android application. One of the screens has UI like that:
[Mockup-UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwFx6.png)

It means: there are a number of columns, the width of column is fixed too, so maybe be it need to scroll horizontally. Each column may have different items number and when scrolling by vertical, all the columns will be scrolled.
So I don't know how to implement this UI. I tried a solution: create some big recyclerview in the two scrollview and then measure all their size:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbars="none">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/horizontalContainer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

        </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

But when the recyclerview is too big, the view is not re-used, the performance to measure all the sized is very bad.
So I found a custom layout manager can make a recycler view like this, but I don't know how to implement, maybe it is mixed from [FixedGridLayoutManager](https://github.com/devunwired/recyclerview-playground/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/recyclerplayground/layout/FixedGridLayoutManager.java) and StaggeredGridLayoutManager.

Comment: http://wiresareobsolete.com/2014/09/building-a-recyclerview-layoutmanager-part-1/

Comment: I tried it as I said in my question: FixedGridLayoutManager, but it is not the same as I want, the size of each item is fixed and the items is straight in a line but which I want is not

Comment: Uncommon solutions need custom solutions. Build Your own one. My link was rather a tutorial how to do it.

Comment: I read it, but I think I need more researching for my custom layout manager. Thanks

Comment: Hi. I have a similar problem. Did you find any solution (I mean some tutorial or direction to create this kind of UI)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view or Consider using a ViewPager here. You can scroll horizontally but one at a time.This won't be as smooth as a list scroll but you can try if the horizontal list is not too long.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article with short but valuable recommendations on creating custom LayoutManagers: http://cases.azoft.com/create-custom-layoutmanager-android/.

I recommend you also to learn in details some examples of different custom options for scrolling lists in various directions. For instance, here you can find Carousel LayoutManager: https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager.

Hope it works for you!